# Adding a variable key/pair to an object gives typscript error on indexing

Tags: typescript

I'm using react and typescript and am getting this error on the last line of the code block below.

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type '{}'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type '{}'. ts(7053)`

from the line `hemisphereInfo[hemisphere][country] = countryInfo;` (see below for full code). It has an issue with the `[country]` bit.

Basically, I'm trying to add an unknown key pair to an object that's typed with an interface.

```
export interface IHemisphere {
  [key: string]: object
  north: {
    [key: string]: object
  }; 
  south: {
   [key: string]: object
  };
}    

const hemisphereInfo: IHemisphere = {
  north: {},
  south: {},
};

for (const hemisphere in hemisphereInfo) {
const countriesInHemisphere: string[] = this.hemiAPI(hemisphere) as unknown as string[];
  
  for (const country in countriesInHemisphere) {
    const countryInfo = this.countryAPI(country);
    hemisphereInfo[hemisphere][country] = countryInfo;
  }
}
```

Firstly, `country` is a string, not a number like it says in the error message. Secondly, I've seen examples solving this problem with strongly typed keys, but I won't know what they keys will be when they come in, so I can't specify each one in the interface.

Comment: `as unknown as string[]` that's like ejecting from type safety. Ideally, `this.hemiAPI` would be typed properly so that TypeScript can tell which type is returned correctly.

Comment: `countriesInHemisphere` is an array, so `for(key in arr)` will return numbers for `key`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch issues going on here.

#### 1)  Difference Between `of` and `in`

When looping through an array, using the syntax `x of array` gives you the keys, while `x in array` gives you the values.  To avoid confusion, it may be better to use a specialized function like `array.forEach()`.

#### 2) All keys are type `string`

When dealing with array keys which are numbers, typescript sees them as `string`.  When dealing with the keys of an `IHemisphere` typescript still gives us `string` instead of the literals `'north'` and `'south'`.

#### 3) Vague index signature

The type for the keys north and south in `IHemisphere` is an object with `string` keys and `object` values.  But they type for unknown keys as described by your index signature is just `object`.

#### Solution

Here is one possible solution. I switched `country in` to `country of` to address #1, added the assertion `hemisphere as keyof IHemisphere` to fix #2, and removed the top-level index signature from `IHemisphere` to fix #3.

```
export interface IHemisphere {
  north: {
    [key: string]: object
  }; 
  south: {
   [key: string]: object
  };
}    

const hemisphereInfo: IHemisphere = {
  north: {},
  south: {},
};

for (const hemisphere in hemisphereInfo) {
const countriesInHemisphere: string[] = this.hemiAPI(hemisphere) as unknown as string[];
  
  for (const country of countriesInHemisphere) {
    const countryInfo = this.countryAPI(country);
    hemisphereInfo[hemisphere as keyof IHemisphere][country] = countryInfo;
  }
}
```

Comment: the ```as keyof``` was a game-changer to learn, thanks!